# Play scala template with Angular got a warning about $index usage

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4, scala-template

I am using Play 2.3 with Scala 2.11.6 and Angular. I have a page template that contains an Angular application.

However, if I use $index in a Scala template like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">{{message}}</div>
```

, I will get this warning during the compilation.

```
possible missing interpolator: detected interpolated identifier `$index`
```

I tried to escape dollar sign with `$$index`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unicode encoding for dolar: `@{"\u0024"}index`.

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages track by @{"\u0024"}index">{{message}}</div>
```

#### Comments

- The problem exists in scala-2.11. It works in scala-2.10.
- There is also the option to disable the entire warning by compiling with `-Xlint:-missing-interpolator`.